# How do I create a script to switch between a Domain and my Workgroup

Tags: batch-file, dns, workgroup

I am searching for a way to switch between my home's workgroup and my work's Domain.

I am sure that it can be done with some commands in batch/python language but I have no idea how to do it...

I'll be happy to get some help..
I heard good things about this site, will be happy to see those things come true :)

Thanks,
Amihay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft suggests](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298593) that you use `netdom`. Note that the machine will have to restart (as it does whenever you change the workgroup).

For example, if you have a computer called `mymachine` that you want to switch the domain `mydomain` you would write:

```
netdom join mymachine /Domain:mydomain /reboot
```

**See Also**:

- [Netdom Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737599%28WS.10%29.aspx) at *Microsoft TechNet* for more information about `netdom`

Comment: First of all, thanks! But how do I return back to the workgroup? If i write the line "netdom join mymachine /Domain:mydomain /reboot" then mymachine will change it's workgourp to the domain "mydomain" but if I want to switch back, can i write "netdom join mymachine /Workgroup:HOME /reboot"??

Comment: @Ami If I understand your follow-up question, then yes; `mydomain` was just a placeholder to indicate the domain to which you want to switch.